# xpath with starts-with fails to locate the element & keyin 'pizza' in yahoo search

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
package p111;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement; 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver; 

public class Yahoo_c
 {

 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 WebDriver wi= new FirefoxDriver();
 wi.get("https://in.yahoo.com/?p=us"); 
WebElement q=wi.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(.,'UHSearch')]")); q.sendKeys("pizza"); 
  }
}


//Actual xpath is :
```

`input id="UHSearchBox`".
I tried with `//*[starts-with(@id,'UHSearch')]` but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have make 2 mistake.

1. You have write wrong xpath
2. If you are able to find element with help of **starts-with** , It will give you more than one elements (Means list of elements).

Use following element finder :

xpath : `//input[@id='UHSearchBox']`

id : `id= UHSearchBox`

css = `input[id='UHSearchBox']` or `#UHSearchBox`